# SQL Server Object Delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

On the 461 certification exam, several questions require:

```
The code must NOT use any object delimiters
```

Any idea what this means?

Thanks

Comment: A google search suggests that this means delimited identifiers . . . the use of square braces.

Comment: See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027

Comment: OK, so don't use unconventional names for objects?! Is this a real problem that is hard to avoid or something?

Comment: Perhaps they want to force you to not use reserved words for identifiers.

Comment: The Test tool itself may not want any square brackets flying around.  CData delimiter for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Statement means, you should not use

1. Quoted identifiers are delimited by double quotation marks (")
2. Bracketed identifiers are delimited by brackets ([ ])

int your code.

so write code with out [] and ""